# Sort by number of occurrence in tables

Tags: mysql, database, sorting

I have a database with many tables.. and each table has stored only IDs. Now what I want to do is:

```
SELECT id FROM table1, table2, table3
GROUP BY id;
```

but I also want to sort them by decreasing order of occurrence.

For example the IDs that are in all 3 tables should appear on top and the IDs appearing in only one table should be at the bottom. Any clue on how to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this too

```
select id from
(
    SELECT id FROM table1
    union all
    select id from table2
    union all
    select id from table3 
) as t
GROUP BY id
order by count(id) desc
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select sum(t1.id IS NOT NULL,t2.id IS NOT NULL, t3.id IS NOT NULL) as total,t1.id from table1 as t1 join table2 as t2 on t1.id=t2.id join table3 as t3 on t3.id = t1.id order by total desc;
```

I am not sure about your problem but this can help

Comment: it is not exactly what i wanted, but it gave me a push to the right direction! thanks!

Comment: it has one issue .. it will not take care id which are not in table1 .. can you post final answer here for us to see :)

Answer (score -2):

```
select id from
(
    SELECT id FROM table1
    union all
    select id from table2
    union all
    select id from table3 
) as t
GROUP BY id
order by id desc
```